# ¿Se refiere “bloque” a “escalera”?

Tags: significado

¿Se refiere "[bloque](https://www.ivap.euskadi.eus/entrada-blog/2018/escribir-la-direccion-postal-es-facil/z16-h2home/es/)" a "escalera" en cuanto a la dirección del domicilio de una persona? Hago la pregunta porque estoy intentando de rellenar los detalles de la dirección en el sitio web de Lycamobile y no he podido encontrar un espacio en blanco para poner “Esc.” (solo se puede poner “bl.”) ¡Muchas gracias!

Comment: Claro que no. Bloque puede ser un edificio dentre de una urbanización, p. ex.

Comment: No es lo mismo, como astutamente indica @Lambie. Le sugiero que se ponga en contacto con el Servicio de Atención al Cliente de Lycamobile y resuelva con ellos su dificultad

Comment: ¡Muchísimas gracias!