# El significado de "sin compromiso de permanencia"

Tags: significado

[Planazo a Fijos y a Móviles](https://www.movistar.es/particulares/fijo/lineas-con-llamadas/planazo-fijos-moviles) de Movistar precisa que "si no dispones de Línea Fija, cuota de alta e instalación 101,08€ (IVA incluido). Ahora, GRATIS (en promoción) y sin compromiso de permanencia." Quisiera confirmar si esto significa que uno puede darse de baja (poner fin al contrato de "Planazo a Fijos y a Móviles") el segundo día después de contratar ese plan sin tener que pagar penalización alguna. Es que es demasiado bueno para ser real... ¡Muchísimas gracias por su ayuda!

Comment: Hombre, yo creo que está fuera del objetivo de este espacio estudiar los contratos de telefonía. La duda deberías trasladarla a un operador autorizado de esa marca para que te explique pormenorizadamente la letra pequeña.

Comment: ¿Pero no ibas a contratar con Lycamobile? (https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/39623/se-refiere-bloque-a-escalera)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si eso significa "sin compromiso de permanencia", no te encuentras obligado a cumplir un tiempo definido en el servicio

Comment: ¡Muchísimas gracias por su asistencia y ayuda!